# Pass the token of an AngularJs controller to a Laravel API

Tags: angularjs, laravel, api, jwt

I am trying to pass the token that I have in my Java Script controller to authenticate to an API in Laravel. From the headers of my controller, I define an '' Authorization ':' Bearer '+ $ scope.token "to be sent to the API. But unfortunately I'm encountering this error:

> "token_not_provided"

Route:

```
Route::get('/members', 'PessoaController@index')->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

I'm use JWTAuth.

My Controller API:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\PessoaRequest;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class PessoaController extends Controller
{

protected $user;

    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $header = $request->header('Authorization');

    return response([
        'status' => 'success'
    ]) ->header('Authorization', $header);
}
```

Angular Controller:

```
(function() {
 app.controller('MemberController', [
'$scope', '$rootScope', 'AppConfig', '$http',
function($scope, $rootScope, AppConfig, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  $rootScope.page.title = 'SEC BASE';

  $rootScope.authenticated = true;
  $scope.token = $rootScope.user.remember_token;
   getMembers();

    // Obtem a listagem de todos os usuarios
  function getMembers() {
      Loading.show();
    $http({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        method: 'GET',
        url: AppConfig.ApiUrl + 'members'
    }).then( response => {
      // console.log(response);
      $scope.members = response.data;
    }).finally(Loading.hide)
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
  }
  }
  ]);
})();
```

Handler.php:

```
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // detect instance
    try {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
            return $this->respondWithError("Token is Invalid");
        }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
            return $this->respondWithError(['error'=>'Token is Expired']);
        }else{
            return $this->respondWithError(['error'=>'Something is wrong']);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Error return:

[image]

Comment: `'Bearer ' + $scope.token`. Notice the space that is missing in your Angular JS code.

Comment: But you have to have that space.

Comment: You have to have that space. Otherwise, it will consider the `Authorization` value as a single string.

Comment: Still returning the same error

Comment: 400 bad request is not an authorization issue. The parameters sent to the request and type of request made is not in the desired form.

Comment: I realized that mistake, my friend. So I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Show me the way in which headers were sent, in the network tab

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l8obx0

Comment: Well, I don't see any authorization header sent with bearer and token.

Comment: 316/5000
Traduzir do: Inglês
I'm passing through the controller AngularJs: $ http ({
       method: 'GET',
       url: AppConfig.ApiUrl + 'members',
    headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = UTF-8 ',
             'Accept': 'application / json',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer' + $ scope.token,
       }

Comment: Ok, there are a few things to consider. You are getting `token_not_provided` which doesn't seem to be present in your `Handler.php`. So, certainly it might be coming from some middleware. Secondly, you will have to allow your frontend application to access your backend API by passing a `Access-control-allow-origin` header in your API response from the backend. Thirdly, like I said, if these are set properly, you should start seeing the authorization header being sent properly in your Request headers.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l8qapj

Comment: ok, so headers are going fine. You will have to see the backend code to understand what you are doing, which throws this bad request.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So, what is that controller or middleware that throws this 400 bad request?

Comment: My api is defined with Route :: get ('/ members', 'PersonController @ index') -> middleware ('jwt.aut'); I apologize for my English.

Comment: ok, so you will have to share the Person controller and the middleware, for me to understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: I edited. All functions are in the question, including the route.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `->middleware('auth:api');` ?

Comment: Not, i'm use Jwt auth. https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

The way you build the request looks good.
It looks like the error comes from the API server that does not receive the token.

If you are running your PHP application using Apache, then you should have a look at [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475885/authorization-header-missing-in-php-post-request).

Apache does not correctly serves the authorization header to the applications. A dedicated rule have to be set in you .htaccess to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If Bearer is not working then you have to send token with parameter data

Not in headers. i also have faced this issue and fixed by sending token with body parameter.

Try to send with Body parameters.

If this doesnt work then also check with changing middleware code

here is 1 line you need to change

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try{
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->input('token'));
        // this will get token from body parameter
```

Comment: the toUser class, would be my user class that I use in authentication?

Comment: toUser us JWTAuth function you can use it directly like i have given in code and pass token in body param