# PHP header request not received

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am passing header by ajax,

```
$.ajax({
     headers: {
          key: value
     }
});
```

I can see the value in `Request Header` in the browser. I am using Codeigniter to get key by `$this->input->get_request_header('key')`.

It is working fine in local but not working on the server.

I have tried `apache_request_headers()` and `$_SERVER` and `getallheaders()` and etc.. but i  cannot see my custom header in this array.

So how to get this custom header by PHP?

Comment: Which version of codeigniter are you using, since 4.0.3 is very different from 3.1.11

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Codeigniter 3 and `Authorization` header. It was working locally but didn't work on the server. I found out that other headers work – I've changed `Authorization` to `Authorization2` just to test. The PHP `getallheaders()` method was also returning all headers with the `Authorization` header filtered out.

This led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791450/3938632) so I've added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

to the `.htaccess` file and the `Authorization` header reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to set a header in an Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader(key, value);
    },
});
```

By sending it that way you don't have to have problems receiving it in your backend with Codeigniter 3.1.11 which is the one that includes the function you are using.

> Returns a single member of the request headers array or NULL if the
> searched header is not found.

```
$this->input->get_request_header('some-header', TRUE);
```